# Grub is not updating grub.cfg

Tags: configuration, grub, upgrade

System: `Linux Debian-10-xxxx 4.19.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.146-1 (2020-09-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux.`

I've got an EFI Linux/Windows dual boot system with clonezilla and gparted entries.
I installed a memtest86 image, and made its grub related entry `43_custom`.

I'm trying to update my grub menu, but `update-grub` only reports Linux options while update and no modification is done to `grub.cfg` even though `update-grub` doesn't report any issue.

I took a look at `menu.lst` and no other entries are listed but Linux. I edited `grub.cfg` to add some entries and this method is working, but what will happend after a kernel update.

By the way, grub customizer was installed a few days ago, but I uninstalled it because it completily changed grub folders structure. After customizer unistall I run these with su permissions:

```
apt-get purge grub-common
apt-get purge grub  
apt-get purge os-prober  
apt-get install grub  
apt-get install os-prober  
update-grub
```

No changes applied to `grub.cfg` after update.
If I rename `grub.cfg` to `grub.cfg.bak` and run `update-grub`, no `grub.cfg` is generated.

update-grub printout:

```
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub 

Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default  
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst  
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...  
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-11-amd64  
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-10-amd64  
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

Any advise will be really welcome, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `grub.cfg` is not updated is because you have `grub-legacy` installed which uses `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.
The [`grub`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/grub) package is a virtual package for `grub-legacy`.

Purge the `grub-legacy` package and install [`grub-efi`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/grub-efi). It contains everything you need (`grub-efi-amd64`, `grub2-common`, etc.). Then (re)install grub and run `update-grub` to regenerate `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
sudo apt purge grub-legacy
sudo apt install grub-efi
sudo grub-install
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dude !  You nailed it !   But now , grub  only shows my linux and windows entries.
what sould I do to get my clonezilla, gparted and memtest 86 options get shown on boot menu ?
Files 40 ,41 & 42_custom are located in /etc/grub.d but update-grub is not detecting them.
And should I edit the files  ?, because it took me some hours to make them working